# How to unit test a class which uses Google Guice?

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice

I have a java class that looks like this:

```
@Inject
PerPixelImageUpdater(PixelUpdaterFactory pixelUpdaterFactory, @Assisted BufferedImage image){
    this.pixelUpdater = pixelUpdaterFactory.create(image);
}

public void someMethod(){
    // some stuff
    this.pixelUpdater.doSomething();
}
```

Google Guice is being used for dependency injection.

I am trying to write unit tests to cover `someMethod()` and I'm not sure the best way to instantiate the class under test.

My initial attempt was to use Guice to create the class:

```
ImageUpdaterFactory imageUpdaterFactory = injector.getInstance(ImageUpdaterFactory.class);
PerPixelImageUpdater perPixelImageUpdater = (PerPixelImageUpdater) imageUpdaterFactory.create(image);
```

But I'm not sure the best way to mock the call to `this.pixelUpdater.doSomething()` so I can test the other logic in the method under different scenarios.

Would it be better to use `new` to call the constructor and pass in a mocked factory? I'm struggling to find any documentation on the recommended best practice when unit testing classes using Guice.

Comment: Inject a mock instance of `ImageUpdaterFactory`, e.g. `Mockito.mock(ImageUpdaterFactory.class)` (assuming it isn't final).

Comment: This may help: https://gist.github.com/virasak/3798194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just rewritten all my unit tests from using Guice-created objects to manually instantiated objects, I can say with certainty that manually creating them is much better for tests. It just gives so much more flexibility. Substituting either just one, or all of the arguments with mocks, fakes, test implementations, is a lot easier.

I'm using the JUnit 5 dependency injection to make this a little easier for myself, having a "standard" extension that provides some of the more often used object graphs that Guice would normally create, and use it when needed. But when testing small parts of that graph, just manually create the objects.

Comment: You mention junit5 dependency injection but you don't give any detail on how to replicate the setup. Can you please add some details ?

Comment: @VittorioBallestra Take a look at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration and https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-parameter-resolution, that should get you started